# Calculate date difference between two dates in spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I am facing difficulties while calculating some sql in athena and spark-sql

If I run this below sql in **Athena** I get the result as 2

```
select date_diff('month',cast('2022-12-29' as date),cast('2023-02-28' as date)) - result 2
```

but If I run the equivalent code in **spark-sql** I am getting output as 1

```scala
spark.sql("select floor(months_between(cast('2023-02-28' as date),cast('2022-12-29' as date)))").show(5,0) - result 1
```

I am wondering if there is any way I can get uniform results in both Athena and Spark

Comment: Have you found the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The two functions do quite different things. In Athena, according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html), `date_diff` does this:

> Specifically, DATEDIFF determines the number of date part boundaries that are crossed between two expressions. For example, suppose that you're calculating the difference in years between two dates, 12-31-2008 and 01-01-2009. In this case, the function returns 1 year despite the fact that these dates are only one day apart. If you are finding the difference in hours between two timestamps, 01-01-2009 8:30:00 and 01-01-2009 10:00:00, the result is 2 hours. If you are finding the difference in hours between two timestamps, 8:30:00 and 10:00:00, the result is 2 hours.

In spark the doc is not as clear but says this:

> Returns number of months between dates date1 and date2. If date1 is later than date2, then the result is positive. A whole number is returned if both inputs have the same day of month or both are the last day of their respective months.

Basically, in spark, the result is a decimal amount of months between the dates like `1.6666`, that reflects the actual duration between the two dates.

To get closer to the behavior of Athena's `date_diff` in spark, you can use `date_trunc` beforehand. As stated in the doc, if both dates share the same day of the month, the result will be an integer.

```scala
spark
  .sql("select months_between(date_trunc('MONTH', '2023-02-28'), date_trunc('MONTH', '2022-12-29')) as diff")
  .show
```

```
+----+
|diff|
+----+
| 2.0|
+----+
```